# django-tenants basics: SHARED_APPS vs TENANT_APPS

Tags: django, django-tenants

I am using [django-tenants](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants) for a multi-tenant app.

In the [docs](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#configure-tenant-and-shared-applications) it talks about setting up `SHARED_APPS` and `TENANT_APPS`.

> SHARED_APPS is a tuple of strings just like INSTALLED_APPS and should
> contain all apps that you want to be synced to public

If I want an app (e.g. `django.contrib.auth`) to be accessible on both the public schema and shared schema, do I include it only in the `SHARED_APPS` or do I need to include it in both `SHARED_APPS` and `TENANT_APPS`?

"SHARED" would imply that everything in this list is accessible via all tenants and the public schema, but the docs seem to imply otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

I am the maintainer of **Django Tenants**.
If you want the same user to be able to access in both shared and tenant you would put it in just **SHARED_APPS**. However this would mean that the same user would be able to get in to multiple tenants I expect you don't want that unless you write a permission table. This would also mean your users are not tenanted.

If you want different users you can put it both the **SHARED_APPS** and the **TENANT_APPS**. Django Tenant always queries local schema/tenant first and if that table doesn't exist it goes to the public schema. This is the way I do it with my project. Beware you need to make sure `django.contrib.sessions` in both **SHARED** & **TENANT** apps otherwise you will get a security problem swapping from one tenant to another.

The other think to look at is [**django-tenant-users**](https://github.com/Corvia/django-tenant-users)

Answer (score 1):

When using django-tenants, your database will contain a `public` schema (ie. directory), and a schema for each tenant, say `tenant1`, `tenant2`, ..

The data of models belonging to a `SHARED_APPS` will end up in the public folder, and will be accessible by all other tenants (schema's). Hence, it is sufficient to only include int once in the `SHARED_APPS`